# Unexpected Output while parsing Html file using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a Basic Html file that contains text inside tags as follows:

```
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>{#One#}</div>
<span>{#Two#}</span>
<b>{#Three#}</b>
<i>four</i>
<td>{#five#}</td>
<sup>{#six#}</sup>
<sub>{#seven#}</sub>
<i>eight</i>
</body>
```

Using Python I wanted to parse this file and and check for a special character (for eg. '{') and if this character is not present then return the line and the number on which its not present. So I wrote a small snippet for it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2

url = "testhtml.html"
page = open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
bdy = soup.find('body')
for lines in bdy:
  for num,line in enumerate(lines,1):
     if "{"  not in word:
        print num,lines
```

However when i run the program I get an strange output: Its shown below:

```
1  
1
1
1
1
1<i>four</i>
1
1
1
1<i>eight</i>
```

Instead of :

```
 4<i>four</i>
 8<i>eight</i>
```

What Am I doing wrong here, it seems like a silly mistake.

Comment: what's `print num,lines<br>` br doing here?

Comment: <br> was a typo, num specifies the number of line on which it is and lines specify the text.

Comment: What is `word`?

Answer (score 0):

Using `find('body')` returns the whole `body` tag with all of its contents as a single element. So, iterating over `bdy` doesn't give what you think.

You need to use `bdy.find_all(True)`, which will return all the tags inside `body`. Then, change `if` statement to `if '{' not in tag.text:`.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
bdy = soup.find('body')
for i, tag in enumerate(bdy.find_all(True), 1):
    if '{' not in tag.text:
        print(i, tag)
```

Output:

```
4 <i>four</i>
8 <i>eight</i>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2

url = "index.html"
page = open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "html.parser")
soup.prettify()
bdy = soup.find('body')
for num, lines in enumerate(bdy):
    for line in lines:
        if line !='\n' and '{' not in line:
            print num, lines
```

Comment: Any reason why you're using regex instead of better available beautifulsoup functions?